# Change the Central Administration administrator

Tags: administration, central-administration

How do you change the Central Administration Administrator in SharePoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a 2010 CA in front of my face, but it's the same as changing any other site collection administrator.  Click the link for Site Collection Administrators, find the central admin web application and set the new owners.

Comment: Ok thank you but I haven't any Site Collection.. I just install SharePoint 2010 and I don't have access to Services Manager or service account configuration. I use the only one account which was asked during installation... What can I do ?

Comment: You mean you want to change the farm account? Or the administrator for the central admin site collection?

Comment: Not really, I wan't my farm account I usually use as Central admin to be the central admin. Habitually I don't have any problems and my farm account is set central administrator during installation but this time, I can connect to central administration with my farm account but for example I can't launch services in central admin... Maybe it's because for the first time my Database is not on the same server than SharePoint ?

Comment: It's OK ! I Just have to add My farm account as an Local Administrator and I become a Central admin !